# Obj-c Expression error - Invalid operands to binary expression ('CGFloat' (aka 'double’))

Tags: ios, objective-c, expression, operands

I have reviewed same types of questions over stack overflow but this is different. Here i want to modulo double value with integer. And compiler is giving below error.

I need to get modulo value of scrollview content offset. For that i have written below code but it is giving me error 'Invalid operands to binary expression ('CGFloat' (aka 'double'))'. Any one please help.

```
scrollView.contentOffset.x % 1024.00;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the simpler solution is this: `(int) scrollView.contentOffset.x % (int)1024.00;`. From what i saw you cant use that operation on float/double

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Modulo operator `%` works only with integers.

You could cast the value(s) to `int`.

```
(int)scrollView.contentOffset.x % 1024;
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use `fmod()`.  [Manpage](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/fmod.3.html).

```
CGFloat remainder = fmod(scrollView.contentOffset.x, 1024.00);
```